# HTML Form works with GET but not with POST

Tags: html, http, forms, post, get

I'm running Firefox 2.0.0.14.

I have a form on a webpage which is working fine with the GET method.

I'm using a plugin to view my browser's HTTP request when submitting the form, and here it is :

```
GET /postComment.php?review=2&comment=Testing HTTP/1.1
...
```

However, if I make the simple change from method=GET to method=POST on the form:

```
GET /postComment.php HTTP/1.1
...
```

It isn't even attempting to POST.

Any possible reasons for this, under any circumstances?

EDIT: Here is the form:

```
<form method=POST action="postComment.php"><input type=hidden name=review value="2"><input type=submit value="Postit">
</form>
```

Comment: What plugin are you using? Are you certain it's working?

Comment: Please post the relevant snippet of your form page's HTML if you would like assitance in verifying its correctness. Thanks-

Comment: "Live HTTP Headers" from the front page of Firefox Web Development plugins. I'm pretty sure it's working because the receiving page isn't picking up any POST variables

Comment: What do yo mean by "is working fine"? How are you accessing the form variables? As far as I know, POST method will not append variables to the query string, that is why you do not get it in your plugin.

Comment: I don't expect POST to affect the query string. I expect to see a POST request though

Comment: What happens if you vary the input fields submitted? For example, put a name attribute on the submit button, and/or add an input field of type "text". Also, apart from Live Http Headers, have you got any other add-ons installed? Maybe one of those is affecting the method value.

Comment: Have you solved this ?

Answer (score 0):

Is the action parameter of the form tag set? Could Javascript be intercepting the post? Some HTML from your form would be helpful, or an example link :)

Comment: There is no JS on the page whatsoever.

Comment: Could you paste the <form> tag and <input type="submit"> you are using please? Are you accidentally duplicating the <form> definition somewhere?

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing your plugin is not capturing the POST variables. Since the output of your plugin is:

```
GET /postComment.php HTTP/1.1
```

How are you catpuring your POST varables? $_POST['key'] or $_REQUEST['key'] should contain your value if the form action and method are set properly.

POST will not be found in the query string.

EDIT:
if you are trying to capture the post value, you can check it with something like this:

```
if (isset($_REQUEST['submit'])) {
   echo $_REQUEST['review'];
}
```

or

```
if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
   echo $_POST['review'];
}
```

Acorn

Comment: I should see:

POST /postComment.php HTTP/1.1
...
Content-Length: xxx

[THE POST DATA]

Comment: Note: I see the proper POST request from other forms using the plugin

Comment: I am checking the POST value like that - isset = false, which is what prompted me to examine the HTTP request using the plugin

Comment: What happens when you change the form action to $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']

Answer (score 0):

I would start by making sure your HTML is valid XHTML.  Wrap attribute values in quotations and end the input elements with />.  Use a valid [DOCTYPE](http://www.w3.org/QA/2002/04/valid-dtd-list.html).

Also, try changing the value of the submit button to "submit" (as that is the default).

Try it out in different browsers, including the latest version of [Firefox](http://firefox.com).

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, your `<form>` tag needs to be adjusted:

```
<form method="post" ... >
```

Secondly, I have a function called debugArray that I use to spit out misbehaving arrays. It's very handy:

```
function debugArray($array){
    echo("<pre>");
    print_r($array);
    echo("</pre>");
}
```

Then, call it in your code like this:

```
debugArray($_POST);
```

By looking at the entire contents of the $_POST array, you can see exactly what is being sent, what is not, and how it is being sent.

I'm willing to wager that one of the following is true:

1. You have a spelling mistake in a field name, remembering that names are case sensetive.
2. Your form field is outside your `<form>` tags.
3. You have a value that is not being escaped correctly, or otherwise being dropped from the $_POST for whatever reason.

Edit: And I would also be inclined to update your copy of Firefox.

Comment: I'm using "print_r($_POST)" and getting nothing ("Array( )")

I've posted the form code above.

Comment: Firefox comment noted, but this is a version bundled with a very popular netbook and so it would be best to support it

Comment: If you're seeing a completely empty $_POST array, this means that your Firefox is not correctly posting the information - are you using some form of privacy software? What version of PHP are you using? What browser? What server (apache, windows)?

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same problem, till I remembered that my .htaccess file hides my PHP extension, and for reasons that someone else can explain (tech stuff) All I did was remove the .php extensión in the action property and it worked.

So, I went from:

```
  action="folder/folder/file.php"
```

To:

```
  action="folder/folder/file"
```

And the print_r($_POST) displayed the full array

I really Hope this helps someone else with the same problem.
And if anyone can technically explain why this is happening, it would be very educational